# QMP Widget fails to load video in QT5.3

Tags: opengl, qt5, mplayer

Below is the code I'm using to display the video however when the program starts all that is seen is a black screen. Hopefully someone on stackies has used GMP Widget before, as completely lost what to do now

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include <QApplication>
#include "qmpwidget.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
QApplication a(argc, argv);

QMPwidget widget;
widget.setMPlayerPath("C:/MPlayer/Mplayer.exe");
widget.show();
widget.start(QStringList("-benchmark"));
widget.load("BigBuckBunny_320x180.mp4");

return a.exec();
}
```

I have also linked the repo for this module as it's too large to list the two files.

[Link to qmpwidget repo](https://github.com/jgehring/qmpwidget)

if anyone has an idea how to solve this that would be great.

Also if anyone has any better solution to creating an RTSP client I am all ears as really struggling to find a decent method of producing this RTSP client.

Answer (score 1):

I tried your source file on Linux and it's working, but I only after I comment the `CONFIG += pipemode` in the `src` directory.

Apparently it is only necessary to compile it to Mac OSX, according to the [documentation](http://qmpwidget.sourceforge.net/doc/):

> Normally, embedding MPlayer into a GUI application is done by
>   attaching the process to an existing window. Unfortunately, this
>   doesn't work on Mac OS X at all, so QMPwidget provides an additional
>   "pipe mode" for running MPlayer on this operating system. Although
>   this mode works on all operating systems, the standard mode should
>   perform significantly better in terms of CPU usage and audio / video
>   synchronization.
>
> The pipe mode is included if the QMake configuration variable pipemode
>   is set.

When I compiled with this option enabled, my tests were always crashing when I tried loading a file.